# how to call MvxDialogViewController as a popover

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to display MxxDialogViewController from a popover and am getting an exception

> 18.35 Request is null - assuming this is a TabBar type situation where ViewDidLoad is called during construction... patching the request now
>   - but watch out for problems with virtual calls during construction

while calling base.ViewDidLoad()

here is what I did to demonstrate the problem as a small sample:

I took N-23 example and added to the first section a new element with the Tapped command

```
new StringElement("test Popover", Tapped),
```

here is Tapped(), as a test I am trying to display the same FirstView in a popover.

```
    private void Tapped()
    {
        var dvc = new FirstView();
        var nc = new UINavigationController(dvc);
        _ardlViewPopover = new UIPopoverController(nc);

        _ardlViewPopover.PresentFromRect(this.View.Frame, this.View, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
    }
```

Should MvxDialogViewController work inside of a popover controller?

Thank you

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is `Request is null`

Try setting the `Request` property for the `FirstView` - e.g. if there are no parameters then use:

```
var dvc = new FirstView();
dvc.Request = MvxViewModelRequest<FirstViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
```

Comment: Thank you Stuart, problem resolved ;~)
What would be a good tutorial/example on MvxViewModelrequest use.

Comment: Thanks - MvvmCross is a community effort and we welcome both suggestions and contributions.