# How do I bind a UILabel with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am writing a small sample app with Xamarin and MvvmCross 6.4.2. I completed the Xamarin.Android version and am now starting the Xamarin.iOS version. I created a view controller for the first screen:

```
[Register("SignInViewController")]
public class SignInViewController : MvxViewController<SignInViewModel>
{
    public SignInViewController() : base(nameof(SignInViewController), null)
    {

    }

    public SignInViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        // Why does it crash when I call base.ViewDidLoad() ?
        //base.ViewDidLoad();

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue;

        var label = new UILabel();
        label.Text = "test";
        label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        label.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(30, 100, 100, 100);

        View.Add(label);

        // This does not seem to work. If I remove it, label.Text will be "test"
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SignInViewController, SignInViewModel>();
        set.Bind(label).For("Text").To(vm => vm.Username);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

I put a test label just to get started and make sure everything works. I'm expecting the label to have the text "username test" since I hard coded it, but it's blank when I run the app. Also, it crashes if I try to call `base.ViewDidLoad()` with null reference exception, which it shouldn't so I think I am missing something important.

Note: I don't want to use MvvmCross 7 because it's still under development.

Comment: Just curious, why do you say MvvmCross 7 is under development? It seems to be pretty stable so far
Also, what tutorial are you following for this, I'm not sure why I didn't see this issue. Have you seen the MvvmCross samples GitHub repo (particularly TipCalc & StarWars)?

Comment: They say they currently have 49 open issues here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/milestones and I couldn't find `MvxAndroidTargetBinding` in MvvmCross 7 which I really need for my projects. I'm not following any tutorial right now.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said about MvvmCross 7. I didn't realize that I need to be targeting minimum Android 10. I was targeting Android 9 before so wasn't able to reference a lot of things like `MvxAndroidTargetBinding` and so thought it was incomplete. It's actually really stable. But I still can't get an iOS project to start without a storyboard...can you please check the sample I put on Github in my other question please?

Comment: This issue was actually because of another issue I had - once I correctly configured my project to not use storyboards at all and only c# classes, I no longer need to do what Jack Hua wrote. I had a rough start with iOS but I get how it works now.

Comment: Im glad you sorted it out! :) Thanks for letting us know, and add your solution as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call             `this.Request = MvxViewModelRequest<SignInViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();`  for you fisrt view
:

```
   public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        // Why does it crash when I call base.ViewDidLoad() ?
        this.Request = MvxViewModelRequest<SignInViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue;

        var label = new UILabel();
        label.Text = "test";
        label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        label.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(30, 100, 100, 100);

        View.Add(label);

        // This does not seem to work. If I remove it, label.Text will be "test"
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SignInViewController, SignInViewModel>();
        set.Bind(label).For("Text").To(vm => vm.Username);
        set.Apply();
    }
```

Refer: [how-to-call-mvxdialogviewcontroller-as-a-popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261543/how-to-call-mvxdialogviewcontroller-as-a-popover))

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found that the real issue was that I wasn't doing things correctly with iOS/MvvmCross. I wanted to code all my views in C# and avoid using storyboard/xib/designer class, but had to change a few things first. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488504/how-to-use-mvvmcross-without-storyboards-in-ios) is what fixed everything for me.