# How to use MvvmCross without storyboards in iOS?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

When I was using MvvmCross 5, I coded all my views and avoided using storyboards for my iOS app by writing this in my `AppDelegate`:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    private MvxIosViewPresenter viewPresenter;

    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MvvmCross Mods:
    /// - Creates a new presenter, which determines how Views are shown
    /// - This example uses a standard presenter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="application"></param>
    /// <param name="launchOptions"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // MvvmCross Mod Start---------------------------------------------

        // This class will determine how Views are shown
        this.viewPresenter = new MvxIosViewPresenter(this, Window);//new ViewPresenter(Window);

        // Init the Setup object, which initializes App.cs
        var setup = new Setup(this, this.viewPresenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        //this.viewPresenter.PresentModalViewController(new ListenViewController(), true);

        // Use IoC to find and start the IMvxAppStart object
        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        // MvvmCross Mod End--------------------------------------------------

        // make the window visible
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }

public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate appDelegate, IMvxIosViewPresenter presenter)
        : base(appDelegate, presenter)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }
}
```

But in MvvmCross 6.4.2, `MvxIosSetup` does not have the base constructor that takes 2 arguments. Instead I have:

```
[Register(nameof(AppDelegate))]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate<Setup, App>
{
}

public class Setup : MvxIosSetup<App>
{
}
```

How can I configure it so that I can code my views without storyboards?

**EDIT**

I created a very small sample app with 1 view model/controller, using MvvmCross 7. The `ViewDidLoad` method never gets called in my `MainViewController`. Can someone please tell me why? I put my code here:

https://github.com/sinight95/TestApp/tree/main/TestApp

Comment: Your ViewModel project determines which page displays first. You don't need to perform the older stuff you were doing. Take a look at the MvvmCross samples, especially the TipCalc and StarWars ones https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples

Comment: Also you don't have to use storyboards as views, you can use XIB's and you can also just use plain C# classes that inherit from an MvxViewController with no XIB or Designer class. You just need to make sure that you pass in your ViewModel type into the MvxViewController

Comment: If I delete the storyboard file, the iOS app will crash when launched with message `Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle`. The Android version works though. I must be missing a configuration in my iOS project?

Comment: Check out your info.plist file. You are probably calling the story bord file to be launched.

Comment: I didn't find anything in my info.plist file. Can you please see my edit and verify my code? It's the smallest possible iOS app with MvvmCross 7. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Lol yeah could you please put it on GitHub

Comment: Ok I put it here https://github.com/sinight95/TestApp/tree/main/TestApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the Setup.cs nor AppDelegate.cs files have anything to do whether you are presenting a storyboard or not. It is usually all up to which Presentation Attributes you are applying to a ViewController.

However, there are some stuff set in the Info.plist that changes how MvvmCross expects things to be set up.

Now in your example App you've put up on GitHub, you can do the following to make it not use the storyboard:

1. Remove `Main.storyboard`
2. In Info.plist set Main interface to (none)
3. In Info.plist set launch images to LaunchScreen.storyboard
4. Remove the scene delegate stuff in Info.plist
5. Remove the constructor in `MainViewController`

What is the main issue here is that you are essentially telling iOS that the ViewController has a storyboard by supplying this constuctor:

```
public MainViewController() : base(nameof(MainViewController), null)
{
}
```

Also are telling iOS to use storyboards through the Info.plist with all the scene delegation stuff.

I've created a PR showing what needs to be changed to make it run without the storboard and show the blue background color you've set on your ViewController.

https://github.com/sinight95/TestApp/pull/1